# Spring/JPA: Entity referenced by a view as a @ManyToOne association

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Currently, my database is organized in a way that I have the following relationships(in a simplified manner):

```
@Entity
class A {
  /*... class A columns */
  @Id @NotNull
  private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "b_view")
class B {
  /* ... same columns as class A, but no setters */
  @Id @NotNull
  private Long id;
}
```

The `B` entity is actually defined by a `VIEW`, which is written in this manner(assuming Postgres):

```
CREATE VIEW b_view AS
  SELECT a.* FROM a WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM filter_table ft WHERE a.id = ft.b_id);
```

The idea here is that `B` references all elements of `A` that are present on `filter_table`. `filter_table` is another view that isn't really important, but it's the result of joining the `A` table with another, unrelated table, through a non-trivial comparison of substrings. These views are done so that I don't need to duplicate and control which elements of `A` also show up in `B`.

All of these are completely fine. `JpaRepository` is working great for `B`(obviously without saving the data, as `B` is Immutable) and it's all good.

However, at one point we have an entity that has a relationship with `B` objects:

```
@Entity
class SortOfRelatedEntity {
  /** ... other columns of SortOfRelatedEntity */

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Fornecedor.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition = "references a(id)"))
  private B b;
}
```

For obvious reasons, I can't make this foreign key reference "b", since `B` is a view. However, I do want the query for searching this attribute to be defined by the `b_view` table, and having the foreign key defined by the underlying table(as written above) would be also nice in order to guarantee DB integrity.

However, when applying the above snippet, my sort-of-related-entity table doesn't create a foreign key as I would have expected. For the record, I'm using Hibernate 5.2.16 atm.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible? Is there something else I should do that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh FFS

I realized my mistake now. This:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition = "references a(id)"))
```

Should have been this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition = "foreign key(b_id) references a(id)"))
```

Notice that the `foreignKeyDefinition` must include `foreign key()`, not just the `references` part.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.